# Как написать "про-всё-про-всё", если это категорически не "про всё, про всё"?

Tags: пунктуация, авторская-пунктуация

Если это скороговорка такая типо и будем говорить про-всё-про-всё.

Не будь двух слов - "про" и "всё", дефис напросился бы, а так?..

А если закавычить эти мои три дефиса?

> Теперь уже и осчастливленная встречей мама, и обретённая дочь стояли и
>   слушали меня заворожённо **"про-всё-про-всё"** – и про Иль-Джезу, и про
>   иезуитов, и про то, когда и как был рождён квартал, в котором нас
>   застал дождь, и где тут самый вкусный шоколад в мире, и где хорошая
>   неаполитанская пицца, и чем отличается от римской, и где настоящую
>   римскую найти, и откуда хороший вид, и многое-многое другое.

Answer (score 2):

Вообще-то собственно фразеологизм - ВСЁ ПРО ВСЁ
(Разг. Экспрес. Абсолютно всё. Дай же мне. Господи, всё про всё знати-разумети)

В нашей фразе нет фразеологизма, просто разговорный повтор, поэтому лучше всё-таки с одним дефисом:

*Теперь уже и осчастливленная встречей мама, и обретённая дочь стояли и слушали меня заворожённо "про всё-про всё" – и про Иль-Джезу, и про иезуитов, и про то, когда и как был рождён квартал, в котором нас застал дождь, и...*.

А кавычки, по-моему, можно оставить, будто бы это словцо не авторское, а от героинь.